# How to take an action when message bubble tapped

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I've been trying to figure out how to insert a handler to take action when a user taps on the message bubble. I've found the section in the readme about "customize your cells" and have tried a couple of different approaches, but so far no luck. Here's what I've tried:

Implemented:

```
- (void)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in my `viewController` as:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    super.collectionView(collectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    println("They tapped!")
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to get called at all for some reason.

The other thing I've tried is implementing:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In my view controller as:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let myDelegate = MyJSQMessagesCollectionViewCellDelegate(origDelegate: cell.delegate!)
    cell.delegate = myDelegate

    return cell;
}
```

This gets called, but the methods in my delegate don't get invoked.

So, any suggestions on how I can properly get my `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellDelegate` put in place so that it gets invoked? Or is my initial attempt to just override the `didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath` method the proper way to go?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it figured out. My attempt to insert my own delegate was actually breaking things (in addition to not accomplishing what I tried to do). Once I removed my "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method my "didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath" started firing.

Comment: Scott, I'm trying to implement this to open a media message into a new view controller. Would you mind sharing a little of your code for didTapMessageBubble...? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @Robert, not sure if this will help, but here's the gist of my method that handles the tap:  
    override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        super.collectionView(collectionView, didTapMessageBubbleAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        var data = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        println("They tapped '\(data.text)'")
    }

Comment: @Robert, I can't figure out how to format the comment, but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: @Robert  How to play a video using JSQMessageViewController??If i Add it shows video message and am not able to download and play a video.....How to do this??I have commented didReceiveMessage method from DemoMessageViewController???